# Callback before effect finishes?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-effects

I am using JQuery-UI. I want to start a new effect before the current one has finished. Is it possible?

Currently, I'm using something like this code:

```
    div1.hide({
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'easeOutQuint',
        effect: 'drop',
        direction : 'up'
    });
    div1.promise().done(function(){
        div2.show();
    });
```

Thank you!

Edit: I 'd like to avoid timers, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it simply by using `setTimeout()`:

```
div1.hide({
    duration: 1000,
    easing: 'easeOutQuint',
    effect: 'drop',
    direction : 'up'
});
setTimeout(function(){
    div2.show();
}, 900);
```

The above will effectively start `div2.show()` aproximately 100 miliseconds before the duration of `div1.hide()` ends (in other words: 900 miliseconds after the 1000-miliseconds animation starts).

Comment: Thank you - seems like I was trying to overcomplicated it with the deferred object, when this is very simple and straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel the current effect using [$.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Comment: I 'd like to have both effects running, but the second would trigger at some point after the first started - sorry for not clarifying this better.

Comment: no worries...setTimeout() will take care of it as @Tadeck shared.